# In Jupyter Lab, How do I clear previous tensorboard graphs?

Tags: macos, tensorboard, jupyter-lab

I am using Jupyter Lab on Mac to run tensorflow and wondering how can I clear all the previous graphs every time I rerun my code? I have a problem in overlaying all the previous graphs on tensorboard whenever I rerun my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should **restart the kernel** through the kernel tab on the top of the notebook.